# Merge hash with another hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I have two hash like

```
h1 = {
  DateTime.new(2015, 7, 1),in_time_zone => 0,
  DateTime.new(2015, 7, 2).in_time_zone => 10, 
  DateTime.new(2015, 7, 4).in_time_zone => 20, 
  DateTime.new(2015, 7, 5).in_time_zone => 5
}

h2 = {
  DateTime.new(2015, 7, 1).in_time_zone => 0,
  DateTime.new(2015, 7, 2).in_time_zone => 0,
  DateTime.new(2015, 7, 3).in_time_zone => 0
}
```

I want to merge `h1` and `h2`, don't merge if key already exist, so that will result look like (datetime format with time zone shortened for readability)

```
result
#=> {
#     Wed, 01 Jul 2015 01:00:00 EST +01:00 => 0,
#     Thu, 02 Jul 2015 01:00:00 EST +01:00 => 10,
#     Fri, 03 Jul 2015 01:00:00 EST +01:00 => 0,
#     Sat, 04 Jul 2015 01:00:00 EST +01:00 => 20,
#     Sun, 05 Jul 2015 01:00:00 EST +01:00 => 5
#   }
```

I have tried with `h1.merge(h2)` and `h2.merge(h1)` but it can be put key and value of `h2` to `h1`.

Comment: Please explain in words what you expect to happen. Do you want the result to sum the values under the same key? Give maximum? Choose one of them at random?

Comment: So, in case both `h1` and `h2` have the same key, you want the key from `h1` to have precedence? If so, @Adrian already told you what to do.

Comment: @Amadan yes, just note using timezone..

Comment: "I have tried with `h1.merge(h2)` and `h2.merge(h1)` but it can be put key and value of `h2` to `h1`." - No, in fact, `h2.merge(h1)` will always have all keys from `h1`, and those keys from `h2` that are absent from `h1`. - "note using timezone" - What about the timezones?

Comment: I suspect you may be looking to make a hash with the values being arrays or sets, but needs more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr = []
h = h1.merge(h2)
h.each{|k, v| arr.include?(v) ? h.delete(k) : arr << v }

#=> {#<DateTime: 2015-07-01T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457205j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>0,
     #<DateTime: 2015-07-04T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457208j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>20,
     #<DateTime: 2015-07-05T00:00:00+00:00 ((2457209j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>=>5}
```

You will have only three key-value pairs, not 5 as you expect, because hash in Ruby is collection of **unique keys** and their values.

Comment: `h` variable not define.

Comment: @itx please checkout edited answer and let me know, if it was helpful